# SQL Trigger throws error but still inserts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a trigger that is supposed to block an insert when @verkoperstatus is 0; this does function, but for some reason it also stops the insert when @verkoperstatus is 1. What could be the root cause behind this?

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[verkoper_check] ON [dbo].[Verkoper]
FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @verkoperstatus bit 
DECLARE @gebruikersnaam varchar(25)
SELECT @gebruikersnaam = gebruikersnaam FROM inserted 
SELECT @verkoperstatus = verkoper FROM Gebruiker WHERE gebruikersnaam = @gebruikersnaam
    IF @verkoperstatus = 0
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('Geen verkoper!',18,1);
            ROLLBACK;
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            COMMIT;
        END
END
```

It should insert when @verkoperstatus is 1, and raise an error when @verkopstatus is 0.

The table Gebruiker is references, which includes a 'gebruikersnaam' and a 'verkoper' column. The value of the 'gebruikersnaam' column is the identifying column which (in this specific case is 'Lars'). Verkoper is a bit column, which indicated if one is a seller or not, so this has the value of a  0 or a 1.

The goal I am trying to achieve is to have an insert on the Verkoper tabel if a 'gebruikersnaam' has the 'verkoper' value of one.
This means if there is a row in Gebruiker with the 'gebruikersnaam' of Lars and the verkoper has a value of 1. This will be an allowed insert into the Verkoper tabel.

As the Verkoper has the following columns: 'gebruikersnaam', 'banknaam', 'rekeningnummer', 'controleoptienaam' and 'creditcardnummer'. When 'gebruikersnaam' corresponds with a 'gebruikersnaam' from the Gebruikers table *AND* has a value of 1 in the 'verkoper' column this record will be allowed to be inserted into the Verkoper table.

As of now there is a row in the Gebruikers column which includes the gebruikersnaam 'Lars' and a verkoper value of '1'. Meaning any SQL Insert with the gebruikersnaam of 'Lars' *should* be allowed into the Verkoper table.

This however does not function the way I believe it should.

These are the tables mentioned above:

```
CREATE TABLE Verkoper (
    gebruikersnaam varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    banknaam varchar(255) NULL,
    rekeningnummer varchar(32) NULL,
    controleoptienaam char(10) NOT NULL,
    creditcardnummer integer NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_Verkoper PRIMARY KEY (gebruikersnaam),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Verkoper_Gebruikersnaam FOREIGN KEY (gebruikersnaam) REFERENCES Gebruiker(gebruikersnaam),
    CONSTRAINT ck_rekening CHECK (rekeningnummer is NOT NULL OR creditcardnummer is NOT NULL),
    CONSTRAINT ck_controleoptie CHECK (controleoptienaam IN('Post', 'Creditcard'))
)

CREATE TABLE  Gebruiker(
    gebruikersnaam varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    voornaam varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    achternaam varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    adresregel_1 varchar(255) NULL,
    adresregel_2 varchar(255) NULL,
    postcode char(7) NULL,
    plaatsnaam varchar(255) NULL,
    land varchar(255) NULL,
    geboortedag char(10) NOT NULL,
    mailbox varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    wachtwoord varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    verkoper bit NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT pk_gebruiker PRIMARY KEY (gebruikersnaam),
)
```

For the inserts I am using the following data:

```
INSERT INTO Gebruiker VALUES ('Lars', 'Lars', 'Last_name', null, null, null, null, null, '04/04/2019', 'lars@mymailbox.cloud', 'MyPassword', 1)

INSERT INTO Verkoper VALUES ('Lars', 'ING', 'NL32ABN32492809', 'Post', null)
```

Comment: Your trigger is flawed; it assumes that you will only `INSERT`/`UPDATE` one row at a time. A trigger fires once per DML statement, not once per row per DML statement. This is likely why you think the trigger is "failing"; it's because it's not doing what you intend.

Comment: You are also committing a transaction you did not start.

Comment: @GSerg a trigger is already within  a transaction. You can't start one within a Trigger as SQL Server doesn't support "nested tranasctions". Although, I admit, the `COMMIT` isn't needed, as that *should* be handled outside of the trigger.

Comment: @Larnu I am not saying there is no transaction to commit. I am saying that trigger will commit a transaction that the calling code started. The calling code will hardly be prepared for that.

Comment: yes, I agree, @GSerg . I was trying to add some extra detail to your comment, as it could be understood to mean (by the OP) that they should start a transaction inside the trigger; which is not the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, however, I *suspect* this is the logic you really need:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[verkoper_check] ON [dbo].[Verkoper]
FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
              FROM inserted i
                   JOIN Gebruiker G ON i.gebruikersnaam = G.gebruikersnaam
              WHERE G.verkoper = 0) BEGIN

        RAISERROR('Geen verkoper!',18,1);
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
END;
```

Comment: This sadly return a `Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.`

Comment: Why is that not desired @Lars? That is exactly what you described you want to happen.

Comment: Well, the insert does not go through even though it should, or so I believe. As verkoper = 1 on the insert I'm trying to achieve.
`INSERT INTO Verkoper VALUES ('Lars', 'ING', 'NL32ABN32492809', 'Post', null)`, account Lars, does have a Verkoper value of 1.

Comment: That `INSERT` statement is meaningless to me @Lars. I don't know what columns those values are being inserted into, and I have no idea how that relates to your table `Gebruiker`. Edit your question to include the DDL and your tables, and then provide sample datab and expect results (this should all be as `text`).

Comment: I have editted the main question, and hope to have included enough information to make my question more clear.

Comment: Hi @Lars, I can't see any DDL or DML in your new edit I'm afraid. We need that to be able to help you here.

Comment: My apologies, it should be there now.

Comment: That DDL and DML works fine for me @Lars. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d804f5de2e29d450b87f874074f9ed48). Unless we can replicate your problem, we can't help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems like my SQL server had some sort of an anomaly, after recreating the database it worked.